# Windows 2016 server administrador no puede conectarse por escritorio remoto

Tags: windows

Mi experiencia en servidores de windows es nula, mil disculpas si es obvia mi pregunta

Al tratar de conectarme por escritorio remoto al servidor windows 2016 me marca el siguiente error:

*Para iniciar de forma remota, debes tener el derecho para iniciar sesión a través de Servicios de escritorio remoto. Los miembros del grupo Administradores tienen este derecho de manera predeterminada. Si el grupo al que perteneces no tiene este derecho o se ha quitado el derecho del grupo Administradores, te lo tendrán que conceder manualmente*

Cabe mencionar que esto me empezó a suceder despues de que le di el privilegio de acceso remoto a un usuario (distinto al de administrador); y lo que quiero es que el administrador vuelva a conectar por el escritorio remoto.

No se si esto se una causa del problema; en el directorio de usuarios tengo dos perfiles:

1. Administrador
2. Administrador.WIN-784e908esk3

No entiendo por que esta el perfil 2!!; segun mis pruebas el que se esta usando es el perfil 2 ya que al guardar un documento se actualiza este perfil

Alguna sugerencia de como resolver este problema?

De antemano agradezco su atención!

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! Este sitio es sobre programacion.. y tu pregunta es sobre configuracion de dispositivos.. hay sitios en la red para eso...

Comment: De acuerdo, muy amable de tu parte!